# Problems Self-Hosting ASP.NET Web API in a Windows Service Application

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-web-api

I've seen some articles on the web describing how to self host an ASP.NET Web API in a Windows service application (see [here](http://www.piotrwalat.net/hosting-web-api-in-windows-service/) and [here](http://lunaverse.wordpress.com/2012/03/30/self-hosting-webapi-as-a-windows-service-with-topshelf/)).  I've written some simple code in VB.NET to start the self host when the service starts and stop it when the service stops, like so:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
    Try
        ' init a new self host configuration using the base address
        _config = New HttpSelfHostConfiguration(New Uri("http://localhost:8080"))

        ' map the URLs into the config
        MapRoutes(_config)

        _server = New HttpSelfHostServer(_config)
        ' start the server and wait for requests
        _server.OpenAsync()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    End Try
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
    Try
        _server.CloseAsync().Wait()
        _server.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    End Try
End Sub
#End Region

Private Sub MapRoutes(ByVal config As HttpSelfHostConfiguration)

    ' add route mappings
    With config.Routes
        .MapHttpRoute("API Default", "api/{controller}/{id}", New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional})
    End With
End Sub
```

My simple controller looks like this:

```
Public Class ClassesController
    Inherits ApiController

    Private _classes As List(Of [Class]) = New List(Of [Class])()

    Public Sub New()

        With _classes
            .Add(New [Class]() With {.ID = 1, .Name = "Geometry"})
            .Add(New [Class]() With {.ID = 2, .Name = "English 101"})
            .Add(New [Class]() With {.ID = 3, .Name = "Psychology 101"})
            .Add(New [Class]() With {.ID = 4, .Name = "Chemistry 101"})
            .Add(New [Class]() With {.ID = 5, .Name = "Physical Education"})
            .Add(New [Class]() With {.ID = 6, .Name = "Study Hall"})
            .Add(New [Class]() With {.ID = 7, .Name = "Wood Shop"})

        End With
    End Sub

    <HttpGet()>
    Public Function GetAll() As HttpResponseMessage

        Dim resp As HttpResponseMessage = Request.CreateResponse(Of List(Of [Class]))(HttpStatusCode.OK, _classes)

        Return resp

    End Function

    <HttpGet()>
    Public Function GetOne(ByVal id As Integer) As HttpResponseMessage

        Dim theClass As [Class] = (From c As [Class] In _classes
                                  Where c.ID = id
                                  Select c).FirstOrDefault()

        If theClass Is Nothing Then
            Return Request.CreateResponse(Of String)(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "The requested class could not be found.")
        End If

        Return Request.CreateResponse(Of [Class])(HttpStatusCode.OK, theClass)

    End Function
End Class
```

The service compiles without a problem, installs using installutil and apparently starts just fine.  However, when I hit the URL the service crashes and leaves the following in my event log:

> Application: WebAPISelfHostPOC.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.Runtime.CallbackException Stack:    at
>   System.Runtime.Fx+AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(System.IAsyncResult)
>   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr)    at
>   System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(System.Object,
>   IntPtr)    at System.Net.ListenerAsyncResult.WaitCallback(UInt32,
>   UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)    at
>   System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32,
>   UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)

And

> Faulting application name: WebAPISelfHostPOC.exe, version: 1.0.0.0,
>   time stamp: 0x50217b41 Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version:
>   6.1.7601.17651, time stamp: 0x4e211319 Exception code: 0xe0434352 Fault offset: 0x0000b9bc Faulting process id: 0x2b58 Faulting
>   application start time: 0x01cd74dbf3f6b8a5 Faulting application path:
>   C:\Gravic\Development\WebAPISelfHostPOC\WebAPISelfHostPOC\bin\Debug\WebAPISelfHostPOC.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll Report Id:
>   3e81d995-e0cf-11e1-b8b3-f80f41109bb9

Can anyone either point me to some sample code that runs a Web API in a Windows Service or point out anything I may have done wrong in my code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The problem turned out to be a set of old assemblies installed in the GAC that were left over from a beta installation of the Web API.  I was able to get my project to reference the new assemblies, and the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Is the account that you are running the service in a local administrator?  Or did you assign permissions to allow access to the url?

Comment: I am running the service under the local system account.

Comment: @RichMiller  That's not going to work unless you explicitly grant it access to the URL. See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583347/c-sharp-httplistener-without-using-netsh-to-register-a-uri

Comment: The problem turned out to be old assemblies installed in my GAC.  I have corrected the problem and I am successfully self-hosting web api in a service running under the local system account.