# Making log file available over local network

Tags: c#, winforms, logging, webserver, httplistener

I currently have a `HttpListener` Webserver implemented that serves my current log, that exists in a `richTextBox`, as a HTML page. This way I can check the status of the application from anywhere on the network.
There are a couple issues with this implementation, it requires admin privileges to run the `netsh` command to make it connectable. However admin privileges are not really available in a `ClickOnce` application. I would like to keep using `ClickOnce` for deployment, so is there another alternative that will not require admin privileges?
Is this possible using `sockets`?
I would like to keep it as simple as possible as I do not to really support `SET` or `POST`, etc.

Comment: _What_ `netsh` command do you use? What port do you listen on? Can you create a service from your web server?

Comment: Ended up using [this implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10128350/78550). But I'm still looking for any other alternatives. Is there a better method? I would think there would be a better method for remote log access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey dude just paste the following code in your application what it will do is if your application does not have admin privileges then it will force application restart in admin mode obviously it will ask first!

```
public static bool IsAdmin()
        {
            WindowsIdentity id = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
            WindowsPrincipal p = new WindowsPrincipal(id);
            return p.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
        }

public static void AqquireAdminMode()
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            startInfo.FileName = System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath;
            startInfo.Verb = "runas";
            try
            {
                Process p = Process.Start(startInfo);
            }
            catch (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception ex)
            {



       return;
        }

        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
    }
```

and this code should be called in form load event

```
if(!IsAdmin())
{
  AqquireAdminMode();
}
```

feel free to ask if you still face problems!

Comment: Sorry, this isn't working for me. If I right click on the executable, "Run as Admin" the webserver starts with no issues. If I double click, I still get `HttpListenerException` ErrorCode 5 - Access Denied. Requiring a netsh command. Any ideas?

Comment: I actually found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10128350/78550), and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

You are using HttpListener and i think that TcpListener could be a alternative for this if you can upload your code then it is possible to illustrate the working of TcpListener