# Trying to setup HttpListener causes an exception, any ideas?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, httplistener

I'm trying to set up a HttpListener for a Server Manager for my Multiplayer Unity Game but I am getting an exception when executing the following code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using WebAPI.Route;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace WebAPI
{
public class WebListener
{
    private int Port = 4444;

    private HttpListener Listener;
    private Thread ListenerThread;
    private bool Bailout = false;

    private List<IRouteController> Routes;

    public WebListener(int port, List<IRouteController> routes)
    {
        Port = port;
        Routes = routes;

        string ip = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName())
            .AddressList
            .First(x => x.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            .ToString();

        Listener = new HttpListener();
        Listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:" + Port + "/");
        Listener.Prefixes.Add("http://127.0.0.1:" + Port + "/");
        Listener.Prefixes.Add("http://" + ip + ":" + Port + " /");
        Listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous;
        Listener.Start();

        ListenerThread = new Thread(Listen);
        ListenerThread.Start();
    }

    ~WebListener()
    {
        Bailout = true;
        if (ListenerThread != null)
            ListenerThread.Join();
    }

    private void Listen()
    {
        while (!Bailout)
        {
            var result = Listener.BeginGetContext(ListenerCallback, Listener);
            result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
        }
    }

    private void ListenerCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        var context = Listener.EndGetContext(result);

        if (context.Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
        {
            string route = context.Request.Url.LocalPath.ToLower();

            var controller = Routes.Where(r => route.Contains(r.GetRoute())).FirstOrDefault();
            if (controller != null)
            {
                var json = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream,
                                            context.Request.ContentEncoding).ReadToEnd();

                controller.RecieveRequest(json);
            }
            else
            {
                WebLogger.LogWarning("Invalid route, no matching controller found: " + route);
            }
        }

        context.Response.Close();
    }

}
}
```

This is the exception I receive on line `Listener.Start();`

> Exception thrown: 'System.Net.HttpListenerException' in
> System.Net.HttpListener.dll The parameter is incorrect.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, any ideas?

Comment: The address list is an array with usually the first address being a IPV6 and second address being IPV4.  You probably need the IPV4 address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `" /"` in your last `Prefixes.Add` leads to your exception.

```
Listener.Prefixes.Add("http://" + ip + ":" + Port + " /");
//                                                   ^  this space above
```

But if you change it to

```
Listener.Prefixes.Add("http://" + ip + ":" + Port + "/");
```

You may get an *Access Denied* exception if you run your application without admin privileges and did not already add the access rights to *all* of your prefixes for your user with `netsh`. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019466/httplistener-access-denied) for more information.

Instead of adding the Prefixes one by one, you can use wildcards like `"http://*:" + Port + "/"` or `"http://+:" + Port + "/"`. With the wildcards you don't need to to get a IPv4 address from your `AddressList` which may not be the interface you want to bind to.

Comment: It works fine except that I cannot get netsh to run without administrator privileges which kind of defeats the point :/. Any ideas?

Comment: @dave: I don't believe `netsh` will run without admin privs. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2583347/9393458) SO post.